# Free user submitted plugins/themes manager for software project

Tags: cms

I am looking for a plugin/themes manager that users will be submitting. Pretty much I would like to have something like these:

http://www.winamp.com/plugins/

http://addons.sonGBirdnest.com/addons

https://addons.mozilla.org/

Comment: I suppose creating one yourself is not an option ?

Comment: Just dont have the time for it :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's anything that won't take any time at all to set up but you could put something together quickly using Drupal without needing to write any additional code.

There's also a module for Joomla called DOCman that appears to be similar to what you want but I don't currently use Joomla myself so can't recommend it's suitability.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your ideas about using drupal? SO would i treat a plugin as a blog post?

Comment: You could create a custom content type called "addon" then users could create this type of content and use the FileField module to attach the addon's to it. You could use the taxonomy module for categorization and the CKK module for any additional fields. Then use the views module to allow people to browse the catalogue. However, Drupal is quite complex if you haven't used it before so you might want to look into it in more detail before making any commitments.

Comment: +1 for Drupal as a good method. If you're really new to Drupal you could do a reasonable job just with core, using taxonomy for categorisation and views, upload for the file attachment, and search for, er, searching.

Comment: I seem to be having some success http://getmusicbee.com/ideas Does any one have any tips on how to make thumbnails for large images? Every guide I keep finding seems to be so overly difficult haha